# How to know what commands you can write in DockerFile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have been looking at many DockerFile in the docker hub( This is one example: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/latest/images/sha256-dcd0251df5efeb39af10af998b45d21436d85e2b9facf12a8800e34ad3d84c91?context=explore)
I am wondering what the procedure is for identifying what goes to DockerFile. For example, I understand what `RUN`, `Copy`, and `WorkDIr` commands do; however, how do you know what to include as `ENV` or environmental variables and, more importantly, what commands are accepted? For example, in the above link: How to figure out what commands I can use for after `ENV`?

```
ENV PYPY_VERSION=7.3.10
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Comment: This is a bit like asking how to know which lines of code you should be writing. The answer comes down to knowing the application being run and the OS/distribution that's running it.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the documentation (right sidebar) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: I have looked at that; it says the syntax for these commands, however, it does not tell you what are the acceptable commands or variables for ENV. The copy, run, etc are self-explanatory.

Comment: ENV can accept any (except special characters, you can escape special characters with quotes and backslashes) key-value pairs and just set them as environment variables for the image/container. There are no commands and variables in the ENV documentation because they don't exist.

Comment: You can read more about environment variables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable